# How to use operator overload to get multiple inputs C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How can I use overloaded >> operator to get multiple different type of inputs from 5 user and assign them to the class members? Also i need to print them all using overloaded << operator so how do i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Input Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358307/c-input-operator-overloading)

Comment: This may also help https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] and show an simple example.